# Why does this Nginx conf allow access to Gitlab on other hostnames/ports?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, port, gitlab, iptables

The whole system is inside a Vagrant box. Nginx is installed in the Vagrant box and Gitlab is in a [docker container](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab). I'm able to reach Gitlab at

```
http://gitlab/
```

as described in `/etc/hosts`, but it's also reachable at

```
http://gitlab:10080/
```

and

```
http://192.168.7.7:10080/
```

But, that port should be closed! Gitlab should be only reachable at my custom URL on port 80.

---

**nginx.conf**

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024; 
}

http {

  upstream gitlab {
    server 192.168.7.7:10080;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab-dw;
    port_in_redirect off;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
  }

}
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - /opt/redis:/var/lib/redis:Z
  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-23
    volumes:
    - /opt/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:Z
    environment:
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm

  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:8.9.6-1
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
    ports:
    - "192.168.7.7:10080:80"
    - "192.168.7.7:5500:5500"
    - "192.168.7.7:10022:22"
    volumes:
    - /opt/gitlab:/home/git/data:Z
    - /opt/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
    - ./gitlab-runner/conf:/etc/gitlab-runner

    - /home/vagrant/certs:/certs
    environment:
    - DEBUG=false

    - DB_ADAPTER=postgresql
    - DB_HOST=postgresql
    - DB_PORT=5432
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production

    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379
    - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022
    - GITLAB_PORT=10080
    - GITLAB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=superrandomsecret

    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENABLED=false
```

---

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

  config.vm.define "jenkins-gitlab" do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.hostname = "jenkins-gitlab"
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 300

    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"

    # Since we mount the dir using NFS we need a private network
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.7.7"

    config.vm.synced_folder "docker-compose", "/home/vagrant/docker-compose"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.gui = false
      vb.memory = 8192
      vb.cpus = 4
    end
  end
end
```

---

**/etc/hosts** (partial, on host)

```
192.168.7.7 gitlab-dw
192.168.7.7  jenkins-gitlab  # VAGRANT: 7fb8647acc689de630f1c7e6550fd33f (jenkins-gitlab) / 9d0a108b-f842-4787-83e5-cfebecbb9d1e
```

---

**/etc/hosts** (on Vagrant guest)

```
192.168.7.7 gitlab-dw
```

[UPDATE]
Also if I change my `DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"` in `/etc/default/docker` the port forwarding is still working.
If I connect into my container via `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash` and make `sudo iptables -L` the iptables of the container looks like:

```
root@11bb3902cb02:/# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: I know, that this gitlab container has an own nginx, but that's not the reason, I tried it with another project, which has no nginx inside it's container.

Comment: Accessing 10080 port directly through 192.168.7.7 means that port does not have to be port-forwarded to the host. But it has to be mapped somehow...

Comment: also if I block everything in iptable with `DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"` and restarting my docker service it's still working

Comment: It has nothing to do with nginx. When you go to port 10080 you bypass nginx completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after destroying the whole vagrant box, checking it out and starting it again, it works now.

maybe one problem was, that I copied the nginx.conf not to  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` as a file called `default`but I copied it to /etc/nginx.conf

now it works, don't know exactly what was the problem, but it's solved now.

Comment: So you didn't change `docker-compose.yml` and you cannot access `http://192.168.7.7:10080/` right now? Did I get it right? Wouldn't you mind to post your current configuration into your answer, b/c there are some people who starred your question, which means they are interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your Nginx instance outside Docker. Hence Docker ports need to be exposed in order for Nginx to connect to a service inside Docker. As soon as they are exposed, you are allowed to connect to that service too, just like Nginx.

It is impossible to solve your problem w/o reconsidering the whole design.

Comment: "expose" is not enough: an exposed port is accessible by other containers within docker, and should not be accessible by anything from the host. The port needs to be mapped from docker to the host, and I don't see a `10080:10080` anywhere in that setting.

Comment: See [here, Docker Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports) The OP is mapping a `gitlab` container's port `80` onto the host's `192.168.7.7:10080`

Comment: `HOST:CONTAINER`: ok, got it.

Comment: even, if my answer is marked as correct, I give you the bounty, thanks for havin' a look!